# How to get data for previous 7 days based on set of dates in groups in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, netezza

I was going through this forum for my query to get data for previous 7 days,but most of them give it for current date.Below is my requirement:

I have a **Table 1** as below:

These are start dates of week which is monday

```
from_date
2016-01-04
2016-01-11
2016-01-18
```

**Table 2**

I have all days of week here starting from monday.Ex: jan 04 - monday to jan 10 - sunday and so on for other weeks also.

```
get_date    flag    value
2016-01-04  N   4
2016-01-05  N   9
2016-01-06  Y   2
2016-01-07  Y   13
2016-01-08  Y   7
2016-01-09  Y   8
2016-01-10  Y   8
2016-01-11  Y   1
2016-01-12  Y   9
2016-01-13  N   8
2016-01-14  N   24
2016-01-15  N   8
2016-01-16  Y   4
2016-01-17  Y   5
2016-01-18  Y   9
2016-01-19  Y   2
2016-01-20  Y   8
2016-01-21  Y   4
2016-01-22  N   9
2016-01-23  N   87
2016-01-24  Y   3
```

**Expected Result**
here wk is the unique number for each start-end dates respectively
avg value is the avg of the values for the dates in that week.

last 2 days of the week are weekend days.

say 2016-01-09 and 2016-01-10 are weekends

```
from_date   get_date    Wk  Total_days  Total_weekdays_flag_Y   Total_weekenddays_flag_Y    Avg_value
2016-01-04  2016-01-10  1   7   3   2   6.714285714
2016-01-11  2016-01-17  2   7   2   2   8.428571429
2016-01-18  2016-01-24  3   7   4   1   17.42857143
```

Could anyone help me with this as I am not good at sql.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using, and what version?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 from_date
, Wk
, count(case when day_of_week <=5 and flag = 'Y' then 1 end) as Total_weekdays_flag_Y   
, count(case when day_of_week > 5 and flag = 'Y' then 1 end) as Total_weekenddays_flag_Y
, avg(value) as Avg_value
from (
 select trunc(get_date,'IW') as from_date
       , (trunc(get_date,'IW')- trunc(date'2016-01-04','IW'))/7 + 1 as Wk
       , flag    
       , value
       , get_date - trunc(get_date,'IW') as day_of_week
       from Table_2)
group by from_date, Wk
order by from_date, Wk;
```

**EDIT:**

```
 /*generate some test_data for table 2*/
 with table_2 (get_date, flag, value) as ( 
 select date'2016-01-03' + level, 
 DECODE(mod(level,3),0,'Y','N'), 
 round(dbms_random.value(0,10)) 
 from dual connect by level < 101 
 ), 
 /*generate some test_weeks for table 1*/
 table_1 (FROM_date) as (select date'2016-01-04' + (level-1)*7 from dual connect by level < 101 ) 
 /*main query */
   select 
  from_date 
 , Wk 
 , count(day_of_week) as total 
 , count(case when day_of_week <=5 and flag = 'Y' then 1 end) as      Total_weekdays_flag_Y   
 , count(case when day_of_week > 5 and flag = 'Y' then 1 end) as      Total_weekenddays_flag_Y 
 , avg(value) as Avg_value 
 from ( 
  select last_value(from_date ignore nulls) over (order by get_date) as from_date 
        ,last_value(Wk ignore nulls) over (order by get_date) as Wk 
        , flag     
        , value 
        , get_date - trunc(get_date,'IW') as day_of_week 
        from Table_2 t2 
        full join (select row_number() over (order by from_date) as wk,from_date from table_1) t1 on t2.get_date = t1.from_date 
   ) 
 group by from_date, Wk 
 having count(day_of_week) > 0 
  order by from_date, Wk
```

Comment: Hi Michael... I cannot have 2016-01-04 hard coded as it might vary based on what there in table..we can assume min date.and 1 more thing to consider is whether it can handle if the start of week of falls on some 30th on one month and gets spilled over to next month?

Comment: Hi, maddy kemen. I dont get what you want. 2016-01-04 - is monday and each 7 days after will be monday. May be you want to group you table not by week in common sence but by intervals from Table 1? But its not clear what is weekend in that case. Could you explain

Comment: I add case for calculting periods

Comment: What I meant was every time it may not start with 2016-01-04.It can be any monday before that also like 2015-12-28 etc and weekend is always sunday.

Answer (score 0):

In the query below, I create the test data right within the query; in final form, you would delete the subqueries `table_1` and `table_2` and use the rest.

The syntax will work from Oracle 11.2 on. In Oracle 11.1, you need to move the column names in factored subqueries to the `select... from dual` part. Or, since you really only have one subquery (`prep`) and an outer query, you can write `prep` as an actual, in-line subquery.

Your arithmetic seems off on the average for the first week.

In your sample output you use `get_date` for the last day of the week. That is odd, since in `table_2` that name has a different meaning. I used `to_date` in my output. I also do not show `total_days` - that is always 7, so why include it at all? (If it is not always 7, then there is something you didn't tell us; anyway, a `count(...)`, if that is what it should be, is easy to add).

```
with
-- begin test data, can be removed in final solution
     table_1 ( from_date ) as (
       select date '2016-01-04' from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-11' from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-18' from dual
     )
     ,
     table_2 ( get_date, flag, value ) as (
       select date '2016-01-04', 'N',  4 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-05', 'N',  9 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-06', 'Y',  2 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-07', 'Y', 13 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-08', 'Y',  7 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-09', 'Y',  8 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-10', 'Y',  8 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-11', 'Y',  1 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-12', 'Y',  9 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-13', 'N',  8 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-14', 'N', 24 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-15', 'N',  8 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-16', 'Y',  4 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-17', 'Y',  5 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-18', 'Y',  9 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-19', 'Y',  2 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-20', 'Y',  8 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-21', 'Y',  4 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-22', 'N',  9 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-23', 'N', 87 from dual union all
       select date '2016-01-24', 'Y',  3 from dual
     ),
-- end test data, continue actual query
     prep ( get_date, flag, value, from_date, wd_flag ) as (
       select t2.get_date, t2.flag, t2.value, t1.from_date,
              case when t2.get_date - t1.from_date <= 4 then 'wd' else 'we' end
       from   table_1 t1 inner join table_2 t2
                         on t2.get_date between t1.from_date and t1.from_date + 6
     )
select from_date,
       from_date + 6 as to_date,
       row_number() over (order by from_date) as wk,
       count(case when flag = 'Y' and wd_flag = 'wd' then 1 end)
                     as total_weekday_Y,
       count(case when flag = 'Y' and wd_flag = 'we' then 1 end)
                     as total_weekend_Y,
       round(avg(value), 6) as avg_value
from   prep
group by from_date;
```

**Output**:

```
FROM_DATE  TO_DATE      WK TOTAL_WEEKDAY_Y TOTAL_WEEKEND_Y  AVG_VALUE
---------- ---------- ---- --------------- --------------- ----------
2016-01-04 2016-01-10    1               3               2   7.285714
2016-01-11 2016-01-17    2               2               2   8.428571
2016-01-18 2016-01-24    3               4               1  17.428571
```

Comment: HI mathguy..thanks for this solution..it works...I was just thinking..whether it will work if one of the week starts on 30th or 31st assuming there would be one..not sure of it though

Comment: @maddykemen - the solution should work perfectly fine - UNLESS there is some special meaning to "month", "year", "week begins in one month but ends in another" etc. Here is what my solution does: It takes each date in `table_1` (it is your responsibility to make sure they are all Mondays, and that ALL the Mondays you need in your final report are included). Then for each of these dates, it takes all the rows in `table_2` that are between that date and that date + 6 (the Sunday of the same week). (continued below)

Comment: The computations don't care if a month or a year end is among those dates - they work perfectly fine in all cases. There is no adjustment needed.